# starting a server with exec command

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, exec, phpseclib

I'm trying to create something based on ssh2 connecting to my vps and then creating some files and running them with exec commands.

I already finished a bigger part which is creating a directory moving files from one directory to another now I need to do something like this

cd directory previously created

```
nohup ./samp03srv
```

but how can i do this with php ?

this is what i got so far

```
    $ssh = new SSH2($request->ip);

    if (!$ssh->login("root", "hpk2o321"))
    {
        return back()->withErrors("Authentication failed! Please check your credentials!");
    }

    $randomNum = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz"), 0, 11);

    $src = $request->path;
    $dest = "/home/servers/$randomNum";

    echo $ssh->exec("cp -r $src $dest");
    echo $ssh->exec('cd '.$dest.' &');
    echo $ssh->exec('chmod +x samp-npc samp03svr announce &');
    echo $ssh->exec('killall samp03svr &');
    echo $ssh->exec('nohup ./samp03svr &');

    echo $ssh->exec('pwd -P');

    $ssh->disconnect();
```

If you need more info please ask!

[image: here is the image]

Comment: So what is the actual issue with that code? Looks like you do try to execute the commands. So what happens? What does your error log file say? What does your syslog file say?

Comment: This is what i get:
chmod: cannot access 'samp-npc': No such file or directory chmod: cannot access 'samp03svr': No such file or directory chmod: cannot access 'announce': No such file or directory nohup: failed to run command './samp03svr': No such file or directory

Comment: Aha, you see how that helps to pin down the issue? So what does that server side created folder contain, since obviously _not_ those files you expect?

Comment: It contains these files. Look at the image I'll edit the post

Comment: I suspect your server side process is not in the folder you expect which is why it does not find the files you expect to be present. Have a try dumping the output of a `pwd` into a log file and check.

Comment: Well pwd is returning me No such file or directory /root

Comment: `pwd` certainly does _not_ return such a message.

Comment: Well now i added & at the end of each command and it only prints /root

Comment: Aha, so it is not in that freshly created folder? Which would explain why it can't access those files?

Comment: Yes, but also when I add & at the end of each command it does not print the errors it did before, cannot acces and such, I'm very confused

Comment: `/home/servers/` is _not_ `/root/`...

Comment: Have you thought of creating a bash script local to the server and just executing it? You can even pass parameters to it so it should work just like you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
echo $ssh->exec("cp -r $src $dest");
echo $ssh->exec('cd '.$dest.' &');
echo $ssh->exec('chmod +x samp-npc samp03svr announce &');
echo $ssh->exec('killall samp03svr &');
echo $ssh->exec('nohup ./samp03svr &');
```

Try `$ssh->exec('cd ' . $dest . '; chmod +x samp-npc samp03svr announce; killall samp03svr; nohup ./samp03svr &');`

The problem with your successive exec's is the fact that the `cd` doesn't persist. A good way to think about exec (esp when it's not using a PTY) is you're SSH'ing into the box, running the command, and then closing the SSH session. If you do that you wouldn't expect a `cd` to persist from one session to the next, would you?

And technically that's not what phpseclib is doing. phpseclib is invoking the exec command as described in the SSH specs. A channel is opened, the command sent, the output returned, and then the SSH server, itself, closes the channel, effectively ending the session. The SSH connection remains open so you don't need to do key exchange or authentication again but the channel is closed.

The way PuTTY and OpenSSH work is they use a mode that I think is best understood as interactive mode. exec is not interactive. You can enable interactive mode in phpseclib with `$ssh->read('#prompt#'); $ssh->write("cp -r $src $dest");` etc.

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#chdir elaborates.